# Why can't I end my if statement with document.getElementById("ID").value = var?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, getelementbyid

I am writing a price checkbox page for my web programming class using javascript where if you check on the boxes and click subtotal, the price is put into a textbox.  The issue I am having is when I end my if statements with `document.getElementById("subtotal").value = total` it isn't populating the textbox.  If I insert an `alert` or `document.write` statement then it will populate it.  Any idea what I am missing?  here is my code with the alerts in place (that I don't want):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title> Price Checkbox </title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <script>
        var total, a = 0;
    </script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function subtotal1()
        {
            if (document.getElementById('apple').checked)
            {
                total = a + .59;
                a = total;
                document.getElementById("subtotal").value = total
                alert(total);
            }
            if(document.getElementById('orange').checked)
            {
                total = a + .49;
                a = total;
                document.getElementById("subtotal").value = total
                alert(total);
            }
            if(document.getElementById('banana').checked)
            {
                total = a + .39;
                a = total;
                document.getElementById("subtotal").value = total
                alert(total);
            }
        }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>

     <form id = "myForm"  action = "">
         <p>
            <label> <input type = "checkbox"  id = "apple"/>
            apple $.59 </label>
            <br />
            <label> <input type = "checkbox"  id = "orange"/>
            orange $.49 </label>
            <br />
            <label> <input type = "checkbox"  id = "banana"/>
            banana $.39 </label>
         </p>

         <button onclick = "subtotal1()">Submit</button>
         <p></p>
         <input type="textbox" id="subtotal"/>
     </form>

</body>
```

Comment: The page is probably posting the form and refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a different approach. Add an event when the checkbox is clicked. This way you can also see what is happening and not leave it when submitting the form. Try this code:

```
<body>

     <form id = "myForm"  action = "">
         <p>
            <label> <input type = "checkbox"  id = "apple"  onclick = "subtotal1();"/>
            apple $.59 </label>
            <br />
            <label> <input type = "checkbox"  id = "orange"  onclick = "subtotal1();"/>
            orange $.49 </label>
            <br />
            <label> <input type = "checkbox"  id = "banana"  onclick = "subtotal1();"/>
            banana $.39 </label>
         </p>

         <button>Submit</button>
         <p></p>
         <input type="textbox" id="subtotal"/>
     </form>

</body>
```